# How to respond to event triggered by Drupal or other module?

Tags: jquery, triggers, drupal-7

```
// Allow other scripts to respond to this event.
  $(document).trigger('drupalOverlayOpen');
```

I saw this in Drupal core. And this in `views infinite scroll` module with params:

```
$(document).trigger('infiniteScrollComplete', [$new_view, $existing_content]);
```

How can I repond to this event in Drupal exactly? Say I want to do something on the DOM when this event happens..

Answer (score 0):

These are the custom events. You can bind your function with these custom events like below:

```
$(document).bind('drupalOverlayOpen', function(){
    // Do your stuff here.
});
```